# How can I set firefox to use google.com/ncr when searching in the address or search bar?

Tags: firefox, google-search

I remember firefox used to store search engines in a XML file. Google is annoying because it automatically uses my home language and it often messes with my search results, since I most often search for programming-related questions.

Google.com/ncr is a redirect, but where can I change this?